# SWRL syntax in Protege

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, protege4, swrl

I am using Protege5.0, and i want to implement SWRL rule ie

```
User(?u), isInActivity(?u, ?cm), ContextMeeting(?cm) -> FamilyContact(?f), hasStatus(?f, "Reject")
```

which means "if user is in meeting then familycontact has status "reject".

This syntax should work and protege doesn't show any error. However, its not working. 
And when i write

```
User(?u), isInActivity(?u, ?cm), ContextMeeting(?cm), FamilyContact(?f) -> hasStatus(?f, "Reject")
```

This syntax works perfectly but its useless when i write complex rules in such format. 
Can anyone explain me the difference between the two formats and also give me a perfect solution?

**More explanation:**

i have a main class **People** & subclasses of People are **Contact & User**. The subclasses of **Contact are FamilyContact, EmployeeContact etc. **The User and Contact** are related by an object property **isContactOf(People,Contact)**.In my ontology there should be only one individual of class **User**. Now, i want to implement SWRL rules, ie **If **user** is in meeting then FamilyContact hasStatus "Reject".** This reject simply means that Family members can not call the user. Other rule is **If user is in meeting then EmployeeContact hasStatus "Pass". hasStatus(Contact,String) is a functional property.**

the second rule syntax works perfectly, however when I want to implement a rule for those instances which are both **EmployeeContact and FamilyContact** then i get problem. eg if i write a rule i.e

`User(?u), isInActivity(?u, ?cm), ContextMeeting(?cm), FamilyContact(?f), EmployeeContact(?e), DifferentFrom(?f,?e)-> hasStatus(?f, "Reject").`

It works somehow but i get a problem. It makes the other instances of EmployeeContact also the Instances of FamilyContact and vice versa.

Comment: I've added an explanation of what's wrong with the rules, but I can't really tell you what the better thing to do is without knowing what you're actually *trying* to do.  What is the rule that you're trying to write *supposed* to accomplish?  The domain and intended meaning isn't clear from context, so a simplified example might help.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor , i edited it, i hope its now more clear

Answer (score 3):

The rule

> User(?u) ∧ isInActivity(?u, ?cm) ∧ ContextMeeting(?cm) → FamilyContact(?f) ∧ hasStatus(?f, "Reject")

uses ?f in the right hand side (the consequent) of the rule, but not on the left (the antecedent). That's not allowed in the language (emphasis added):

> #### [2.1. Rules](http://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/#2.1)
>
> Atoms may refer to individuals, data literals, individual variables or
>   data variables. Variables are treated as universally quantified, with
>   their scope limited to a given rule. **As usual, only variables that
>   occur in the antecedent of a rule may occur in the consequent (a
>   condition usually referred to as "safety").** This safety condition does
>   not, in fact, restrict the expressive power of the language (because
>   existentials can already be captured using OWL someValuesFrom
>   restrictions).

If it were legal, then your rule would mean:

> For every u, cm, and f,
>
> - **if** u is a User and cm is a ContextMeeting and u is in cm,
> - **then** f is a family contact and has status "reject".

But since there are no constraints on ?f, this says that *any* user is in *any* context meeting, then *everything* is a family contact with status "reject", and that's probably not what you want.  Shouldn't ?f be related to ?u somehow?  The proposed alternative:

> User(?u) ∧ isInActivity(?u, ?cm) ∧ ContextMeeting(?cm) ∧ FamilyContact(?f) →  hasStatus(?f, "Reject")

has a similar problem.  It would mean:

> For every u, cm, and f,
>
> - **if** u is a User and cm is a ContextMeeting and u is in cm and f is a family contact,
> - **then** f has status "reject".

There's still no connection between u and f, so this says that if **any** user is in **any** context meeting, then **every** family contact has status "reject".  That doesn't seem like what you'd want either.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. I understood your explanation. and yeah the user and FamilyContact are related by the object property  "isContactOf" ie User(?u),isContactOf(?u,?f),FamilyContact(?f). And also in my ontology there should be only one individual of User, not more. Btw thanks for ur detailed explanation. I'll try out the adding the relation between user and FamilyContact in the SWRL rule.

Comment: @user2083529 Then you'd need to add that connection to the antecedent of the rule.  You don't necessarily have to specify all the class conditions, though.  E.g., if you already have **frobsBar(?f,?b)**, then you probably don't need to make it **frobsBar(?f,?b), Frobber(?f), Bar(?b)** since the domain and range of the property might already guarantee that.

Comment: yeah i understand that. However, what i am dealing with is different. i have `People` as main class and `user`, `familyContact` as subclasses of `People`. The domain and range of `"isContactOf"` is `People` and `Contact`. `FamilyContact` is actually subclass of `Contact` which intern is subclass of `People`. Anyway i think i have to define everything in the rule.